# How to create a table during the module installation

Tags: 7, installation, database

I'm trying to create a module for Drupal 7 and I need to create 3 tables and populate it. But first i need to create it.

In the file mymodule.install I have got

```
function mymodule_install() {

}

function mymodule_uninstall() {

}


function myodule_schema() {
  $schema['mymodule_table'] = array(
    'description' => t('First table'),
    'fields' => array(
      'id' => array(
        'description' => t('My unique identifier'),
        'type' => 'int',
        'unsigned' => true,
        'not null' => true,
      ),
      'list' => array(
        'description' => t('list'),
        'type' => 'varchar',
        'not null' => true,
      ),
    ),
    'primary key' => array('id'),
  );
  return $schema;     
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Every time I test the module, I disable it -> uninstall -> Performance clear cache -> enable it.

Comment: If you have drush and devel installed you could use `drush devel-reinstall mymodule` to quickly reinstall your module

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're missing the `length` property for the `varchar` column ('list'). `length` is required so the `CREATE TABLE` query will fail.

From the [Schema API docs](http://drupal.org/node/146939):

> All parameters apart from 'type' are optional except that type 'numeric' columns must specify 'precision' and 'scale', and 'varchar' columns must specify 'length'.

Answer (score 4):

`myodule_schema` has a typo. An `m` is missing after the `y`.

Comment: Thanks BetaRide, it was a transcription mistake. I give you one vote up because you have read my post and actually I really found a spelling mistake on the name of the function eh eh